# Direct update in mobilefirst ionic-cordova application failed after downloading the update from server?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

After updating the web resources in the mfp server,and after the downloading is completed while extracting the files getting this error.Please refer to the screenshot for  the error.[direct-update-extract-failed-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybsrp.jpg)

The plugin version of cordova-mfp-plugin is 8.0.2018090311 and ionic version is 3.20. Please help me to resolve this error. Thanks.

Comment: Whats the cordova CLI version and the mfpdev-cli version?

Comment: Also what is your cordova-android version?

Comment: @vivin K cordova version is 8.0.0 and mfpdev-cli is 8.0.0-2018040312.

Comment: @Keerthi find ur information. 

Installed platforms:
  android 6.4.0
Available platforms:
  browser ~5.0.1
  ios ~4.5.4
  osx ~4.0.1
  windows ~5.0.0
  www ^3.12.0

Comment: Did you see this https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-err-file-not-found-file-android-asset-www-index-html/91629

Comment: @core114 could not find solution here . can u please refer to the screenshot that I attached.

Answer (score 0):

This is known issue with latest cordova plugman 8.0.0 (lower cordova-android versions)and mfpdev-cli,and this issue is being worked on.You can use mfpdev-cli present here :
[mfpdev-cli](https://ibm.box.com/s/etg43q7xlkw7ug3uvssdjlxxxh399s16)

steps use:

uninstall existing cli :

> npm uninstall -g mfpdev-cli

Install mfpdev-cli :

> npm install -g path-to-mfpdev-cli.tgz

run command below command to receive direct update

> mfpdev app webupdate

OR

use cordova@7.1 to add cordova-android@6.4.0 and[mfpdev-cli@8.0.2017102406](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mfpdev-cli/v/8.0.2017102406)

Comment: Thanks really appreciate this. can you let me know one thing, the mfpdev-cli that you mentioned . Is it officially available in any of the IBM doc pages.

Comment: No it is not available yet  it is just a workaround fix will be available in upcoming ifixes.Otheriwise  you can use cordova@7.1 to add cordova-android@6.4.0 and mfpdev-cli@8.0.2017102406

Comment: Thanks the error is removed and application gets reloaded but could not find the changes after direct update. can u help why this is so?

Comment: I have the updated some html and ts file contents and then tried but didn't get update reflected in my application

Comment: I have checked it multiple times , updated src folder by adding some arbitrary text in home.html  file and ran the mfpdev app webupdate. but still after direct update is completed the application is not updated. Kindly help me on this.

Comment: can u send me the invitation link to vikasthakurbksc@gmail.com.

Comment: Done @vikaskumar

Comment: Alternatively you can use this link to get invitation https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2017/05/26/come-chat-with-us/#how-to-join-us-on-slack